# Do something when "select" not changed

Tags: web-applications, onchange

I have a select tag with some options and a function which is triggered "on change". Is there a way to trigger another function, when the user clicks the select list but doesn't change anything? Like "on no change"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could add your function to "onClick" or "onFocus" attribute and check if the user hasnt changed anything, it should do the trick.